# what the equivalent of WINHTTP_NO_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT under Wininet?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, wininet, winhttp

under **winhttp** I can do

```
WinHttpSetOption(Result, WINHTTP_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT, WINHTTP_NO_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT, 0);
```

Under **Wininet**, i already found the `INTERNET_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT` option, but I can't find the equivalent for `WINHTTP_NO_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT`. How to do under wininet ?

Comment: Do you want to choose another authentication scheme or anonymous access to the server?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT just  anonymous access to the server.

Comment: For FTP server, you can set user name and password to `NULL` when calling [`InternetConnect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetconnecta) function. For HTTP server, try to set [`INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/api-flags) flag when calling  `HttpOpenRequest` and `InternetOpenUrl` (for HTTP requests).

Comment: Has this issue solved?